# Can someone help me use this Json file in c#?

Tags: c#, json, .net, winforms, json.net

I have been trying to display contents of a json file in a textbox for the past 6 hours and got nowhere.
here's the c# code

```
        private thruster Getthruster()
        {
            string text = File.ReadAllText(@"./thrusters.json");
            List<thruster> test = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<thruster>>(text);
        
            textBox1.Text = text;
        
            foreach (var item in test)
            {
                textBox1.Text = item.type;
            }
            return Getthruster();
        }


        public class thruster
        {
            public string id { get; set; }
            public string type { get; set; }
            public string placement { get; set; }
        }
```

```json
{
  "thruster": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "type": "tunnel",
      "placement": "bow"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "type": "tunnel",
      "placement": "bow"
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "type": "azimuth",
      "placement": "bow"
    },
    {
      "id": 5,
      "type": "azimuth",
      "placement": "stern"
    },
    {
      "id": 5,
      "type": "tunnel",
      "placement": "stern"
    },
    {
      "id": 6,
      "type": "azimuth_propulsion"
    },
    {
      "id": 7,
      "type": "azimuth_propulsion"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: And here's the Json file:
`
{
 "thruster": [
  {
   "id": 1,
   "type": "tunnel",
   "placement": "bow"
  },
  {
   "id": 2,
   "type": "tunnel",
   "placement": "bow"
  },
  {
   "id": 3,
   "type": "azimuth",
   "placement": "bow"
  },
  {
   "id": 5,
   "type": "azimuth",
   "placement": "stern"
  },
  {
   "id": 5,
   "type": "tunnel",
   "placement": "stern"
  },
  {
   "id": 6,
   "type": "azimuth_propulsion"
  },
  {
   "id": 7,
   "type": "azimuth_propulsion"
  }
 ]
}

`

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75383117/edit) your question and add json data. do not misuse the comment section

Comment: remove foreach loop and deserialization ... and you will have *contents of a json file in a textbox*

Answer (score 1):

To start, you are running into a `StackOverflowException` since you are calling the same method (`Getthruster()`) inside the same method without any exit condition.

After this, your json file seems to be incorrect. You have there a `Dictionary<string,thruster[]>` and not a `thruster[]` (Or List).

Your json for a `thruster[]` or `List<thruster>` should be something like:

```json
[
  {
    "id": "1",
    "type": "t",
    "placement": "top"
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "type": "t",
    "placement": "top"
  }
]
```

Comment: sorry, I do not see anything wrong in the json from OP

Answer (score 0):

you have an object inside of a json string, but you try to serialize it as it is an array. You can use this code that deserializes  an array inside of your json

```
 List<thruster> test = JObject.Parse(text)["thruster"].ToObject<List<thruster>>();
```